# Simple probability

Tags: probability

At a dance there are $n=3$ married couples: Ann and Andy, Betty and Boris, and Danielle and Dan. The wives select a husband at random with whom to share a dance. What is the probability that each of the three men dances with a woman other than his spouse.

In each pair, I denoted wives with a lowercase letter and husbands with an uppercase. The pairs are aA, bB, and dD. I counted $9$ ways in which women could select men. 
aA, aB, aD
bB, bA, bD
dD, dA, dB

So there are $6$ ways to select other spouses. The probability is $\frac{6}{9}$, which is $0.67$, but the answer is $0.33$. What's wrong? Maybe I misunderstood the question, because English is my second language. Please help.

Comment: Which triples of assignments are simultaneously compatible?  For instance $\{aA, aB, \langle\text{anything}\rangle\}$ is not a possibility.  The question is not about choices taken independently, it's about simultaneous triples of choices that are compatible.  (An example of a compatible triple is $\{aB, bD, dA\}$.  What fraction of compatible triples have no wife-husband pairing at all?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:  The total number of ways you can pair them is ofcourse 9.  A can choose to dance with b or c.  Suppose he chooses to dance with b.  B will have a choice between a and c. She has to select a because C cannot dance with c.  Similarly, If A chooses to dance with c, C will have a choice to dance with b, because B cannot dance with b.  Thus either way, there are only three possible choices and thus 3/9  = 0.333

Comment: You yourself just counted 6 ways they can divide into pairs. Didn't you?

Comment: Oh I got you so you mean that the probability that the first man will dance with the woman other than his wife is 2/3, for the second one it is 1/2 and for the third it is 1. Multiplying them we get 1/3. Ok. thanks!